# Linkedin Authentication using a WebView on Android occasionally fails

Tags: javascript, android, linkedin-api

For some of our users, Linkedin authentication using a WebView doesn't work.

1. Linkedin WebView is displayed within an activity
2. The user types in the credentials
3. The Linkedin login screen just get refreshed

Some hints:

Not sure if it's related, but in my attempt to understand what is going on, I logged a Error and a Warning message using setWebChromeClient and got these:

1. Error: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined -- From line 233 of https://www.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/lib/espany/1.0.0/espany.js
2. Warning: webkitURL' is deprecated. Please use 'URL' instead. -- From line 31 of https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=25kaepc6rgo1820ap1rglmzr4-edgsl2z4e4gk56cy2m5kbpp1q-dtx8oyvln9y03x1ku6t0abhc9-cl5mre9823ndhfdrl4nozaofi-6isi7fr80gagap7736arbauct-8ohb0iio22nbqe1w8et54sawe-13kfns70b5ghzzqxzr194d2jo-cr2cf88zdeizqhuobqtot8sge-amjylk8w8039f2lwlov2e4nmc-47qp7uw3i5i1pqeovirlcc070-5pmigtkow46izwzcb8m1b57ly-br7xw7z07pbsy9z5545ze80zu-aikuay313zihm7be1fml6lb8y-7vr4nuab43rzvy2pgq7yvvxjk-9qa4rfxekcw3lt2c06h7p0kmf